# Set default values for an existing function in scala

Tags: scala

Here is an example:

```
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation
import org.jfree.chart.{ChartFactory => cf, JFreeChart}
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset


package object sfreechart {
  object xyl {
    def xyline(
                dataset: XYDataset, 
                title: String = "XY line chart", xAxisLabel: String = "x", yAxisLabel: String = "y",
                orientation: PlotOrientation = PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, legend: Boolean = true,
                tooltips: Boolean = true, urls: Boolean = true
              ): JFreeChart = {
      cf.createXYLineChart(
        title, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel,
        dataset, orientation, legend,
        tooltips, urls
      )
    }
  }
}
```

I am just trying to provide sensible defaults for a plotting function in jFreeChart, so that a chart can be created without much ceremony. The above code works fine, but involves some boring boilerplates. Is there a cleverer trick?

Ideally I should only need to do something like this:

```
val xyline = cf.createXYLineChart.setDefaults(title = "XY line chart", ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any such trick. Also, IMHO, there really isn't any boilerplate here. Its the minimum you could write to convey this requirement.